# Request return wrong values after update query on Jhipster Java Back service

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jhipster, ehcache

On my application, in my Java Backend, I call with SOAP UI a service to retrieve values (SELECT) that I receive.

Then, I make an update that impacts the previous result.

Then, on SOAP UI, I call my service again with the same SELECT request in order to view my modifications but the result is the same as during the first call, my modifications are not returned. I check the database, my modifications are present.

My application is under JHIPSTER 7.1 and my database is under Postgres. I am using ehcache with hibernate and I suspect the cache is the cause of this problem because as soon as I restart my service the query returns the correct values.

Do you know why I am seeing this problem and how to solve it?

**EDIT 1**

Ehcache configuration

```
jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      ...
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false <- change from true (KO) to false (OK)
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
```

End for the profils

**Dev** (current profil with problem)

```
jhipster:
  cache: # Cache configuration
    ehcache: # Ehcache configuration
      time-to-live-seconds: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour in the cache
      max-entries: 100 # Number of objects in each cache entry
```

**Prod**

```
jhipster:
  http:
    cache: # Used by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter
      timeToLiveInDays: 1461
  cache: # Cache configuration
    ehcache: # Ehcache configuration
      time-to-live-seconds: 3600 # By default objects stay 1 hour in the cache
      max-entries: 1000 # Number of objects in each cache entry
```

All my request are subscribe with RESP API. I'm new on ehcache and in my code, I don't put any code about it on my differents services ...

**EDIT 2**

Example of my repository use JPA
[image]

Comment: Looks like a caching problem but without knowing more and especially seeing some code that's all I can say. You could try to disable the cache or look how to make your update invalidate or directly update it.

Comment: Yes, I have disable it with `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache` from true to false. Effectively, the problem has disapear ... But i don't know why. I added the configuration in my question, what do you need more for help me ?

I have also a parameter `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` witch was "false". Is it normal ?

Comment: Yeah, query cache being disabled would be normal. You should read up on those caches and other components to understand what they are doing but in short terms: a) query cache caches the result of a query to return it when you execute the same statement with the same parameters again. b) 2nd level cache caches entities beyond the scope of a hibernate session (often bound to a transaction) which would be the 1st level. So if you have a method that actually looks up an entity by id it could retrieve it from 2nd level instead of querying the DB. ...

Comment: 2nd level cache can help in many situations if you know what you're doing but you also need to make sure it is updated. Hibernate can take care of this if you're updating entities in code and let Hibernate do the DB updates, but if you're using update queries it won't know which entities are affected and in that case it's up to you to update or invalidate the 2nd level cache.

Answer (score 0):

How do you update the database? Using the Spring Data repository? Normally, when a table is updated, Hibernate will clear the cache for this table. So everything should be in sync.

It won't be the case if you update in a out-of-Hibernate way. Also, look at your caching strategy for the entity. A READ_ONLY entity is not expected to change so Hibernate won't evict.

Comment: All update request are made with hibernate with JPA repository classe, there is no "custom" request for create or update data. (example in EDIT 2). When I create or update a Saison, I use this repository with an object

Comment: So it probably comes from the strategy used at some level of configuration. Which prevent eviction. Put Hibernate log in debug or trace, it should give you an idea